# The best way to replace your app on GP (lost keyfile)

Tags: android, apk, google-play

A year ago I made an Android application and published it on Google Play. Now I want to update it but sadly have lost the keyfile for signing apk.

I know I need to unpublish my app from GP first, change the package name, and upload the updated apk signed with newly generated keyfiles. This way I also lose all users and ratings.

Can I make this process any less *painful* (meaning not losing ratings and/or users)?

I am also wondering if this way I can have the same app name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your old app and add new one. You can't connect your old app to a new one in any way.

Do not delete old one immediately. Change it's description asking users to move to a new application.

Comment: Can I keep the app's name?

Comment: I never checked this, but AFAIK application names on market do not need to be unique. So I think you can keep name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to recovery your key with this.

[Android keystore password recover](http://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/)

I hope you can recover it. If you can't, then I'm afraid you will have to endure this painfull process of creating new package and upload a baby app in the play store.

Comment: This would apply if one would need to recover the password of *the keyfile*. But I don't have *the keyfile* itself.